# What's a better way to write a PHP page?

Tags: php, format, structure

I learned PHP from the internet without taking any formal lessons. Most tutorials give a good idea of how to write PHP, but never how to "use" it.

Before starting my first website project, which of the following is technically a better way to make a website using PHP? My pages will be using the .PHP extension dominantly.

Method A:

```
<?php
    $a = string;
    $b = string;
    $c = array(items);

    echo "
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>";

    include ("PATH/PAGECONTENTS");
    include ("PATH/SIDEBAR");
    include ("PATH/FOOTER");

    echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Method B:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<?php
    $a = string;
    $b = string;
    $c = array(items);
?>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
    include ("PATH/PAGECONTENTS");
    include ("PATH/SIDEBAR");
    include ("PATH/FOOTER");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In method A, the entire document is in PHP, while method B means mixing HTML with PHP. Method A somehow feels like a more correct way to write a PHP page.

However, in method B, I'll be able to state the !DOCTYPE before the rest of the page loads. This feels more correct in terms of writing an XHTML page.

Since both pages return the same source code, I can't exactly compare by validating the two files.

Is one way better than the other, or does it really not matter?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, this question is really difficult to phrase for a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method B** is Better.

It will be more good if you **include** and do **variable assignment** in the beginning:

```
<?php

  include ("PATH/PAGECONTENTS");
  include ("PATH/SIDEBAR");
  include ("PATH/FOOTER");

  $a = string;
  $b = string;
  $c = array(items);

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body></body>

</html>
```

Moreover, **<!DOCTYPE>** is a Client Side HTML tag. It has nothing to do with the Server.

Find more at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've changed the part about <!DOCTYPE>. Why is it better to have the include in the beginning? Wouldn't it cause the included content to show up before the <!DOCTYPE> and <html> tags?

Comment: Code becomes Cleaner if we keep includes in the beginning. Nothing will show up before <!DOCTYPE> until you 'echo' something (which we usually do in the <body> tag).

Comment: It's always recommended to have all the heavy lifting from the clients browser in order to give the server less operations and decrease it's load